# Hibernate Envers throwing ContainerInitializationException in Micronaut App in AWS Lambda

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, micronaut, hibernate-envers

I am trying to integrate auditing into my Micronaut application which is being served in an AWS Lambda. This works perfectly when I run the application locally, however when I deploy this to my Lambda, the application throws the following exception:

```
io.micronaut.context.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Exception thrown instantiating MicronautLambdaRuntimeHandler
at io.micronaut.function.aws.runtime.MicronautLambdaRuntime.createRequestHandler(MicronautLambdaRuntime.java:40)
at io.micronaut.function.aws.runtime.AbstractMicronautLambdaRuntime.createHandler(AbstractMicronautLambdaRuntime.java:219)
at io.micronaut.function.aws.runtime.AbstractMicronautLambdaRuntime.startRuntimeApiEventLoop(AbstractMicronautLambdaRuntime.java:340)
at io.micronaut.function.aws.runtime.AbstractMicronautLambdaRuntime.run(AbstractMicronautLambdaRuntime.java:146)
at io.micronaut.function.aws.runtime.MicronautLambdaRuntime.main(MicronautLambdaRuntime.java:50)
Caused by: com.amazonaws.serverless.exceptions.ContainerInitializationException: Error starting Micronaut container: Bean definition [io.micronaut.transaction.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager] could not be loaded: Error instantiating bean of type [org.hibernate.boot.SessionFactoryBuilder]
Path Taken: new HibernateTransactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory,DataSource dataSource,Interceptor entityInterceptor,String name) --> new HibernateTransactionManager([SessionFactory sessionFactory],DataSource dataSource,Interceptor entityInterceptor,String name) --> SessionFactory.buildHibernateSessionFactoryBuilder([SessionFactoryBuilder sessionFactoryBuilder]) --> SessionFactoryBuilder.buildHibernateSessionFactoryBuilder([Metadata metadata],JpaConfiguration jpaConfiguration,String name)
at io.micronaut.function.aws.proxy.MicronautLambdaContainerHandler.initialize(MicronautLambdaContainerHandler.java:263)
at io.micronaut.function.aws.proxy.MicronautLambdaContainerHandler.<init>(MicronautLambdaContainerHandler.java:196)
at io.micronaut.function.aws.proxy.MicronautLambdaContainerHandler.<init>(MicronautLambdaContainerHandler.java:149)
at io.micronaut.function.aws.proxy.MicronautLambdaHandler.<init>(MicronautLambdaHandler.java:54)
at io.micronaut.function.aws.runtime.MicronautLambdaRuntime.createRequestHandler(MicronautLambdaRuntime.java:38)
Caused by: io.micronaut.context.exceptions.BeanInstantiationException: Bean definition [io.micronaut.transaction.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager] could not be loaded: Error instantiating bean of type [org.hibernate.boot.SessionFactoryBuilder]
Path Taken: new HibernateTransactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory,DataSource dataSource,Interceptor entityInterceptor,String name) --> new HibernateTransactionManager([SessionFactory sessionFactory],DataSource dataSource,Interceptor entityInterceptor,String name) --> SessionFactory.buildHibernateSessionFactoryBuilder([SessionFactoryBuilder sessionFactoryBuilder]) --> SessionFactoryBuilder.buildHibernateSessionFactoryBuilder([Metadata metadata],JpaConfiguration jpaConfiguration,String name)
at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.initializeContext(DefaultBeanContext.java:1921)
at io.micronaut.context.DefaultApplicationContext.initializeContext(DefaultApplicationContext.java:249)
at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.readAllBeanDefinitionClasses(DefaultBeanContext.java:3326)
at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.finalizeConfiguration(DefaultBeanContext.java:3684)
at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.start(DefaultBeanContext.java:341)
at io.micronaut.context.DefaultApplicationContext.start(DefaultApplicationContext.java:194)
at io.micronaut.function.aws.proxy.MicronautLambdaContainerHandler.initialize(MicronautLambdaContainerHandler.java:259)
Caused by: io.micronaut.context.exceptions.BeanInstantiationException: Error instantiating bean of type [org.hibernate.boot.SessionFactoryBuilder]
Path Taken: new HibernateTransactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory,DataSource dataSource,Interceptor entityInterceptor,String name) --> new HibernateTransactionManager([SessionFactory sessionFactory],DataSource dataSource,Interceptor entityInterceptor,String name) --> SessionFactory.buildHibernateSessionFactoryBuilder([SessionFactoryBuilder sessionFactoryBuilder]) --> SessionFactoryBuilder.buildHibernateSessionFactoryBuilder([Metadata metadata],JpaConfiguration jpaConfiguration,String name)
at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveByBeanFactory(DefaultBeanContext.java:2367)
at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:2305)
at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:2251)
at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.createRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:3016)
at io.micronaut.context.SingletonScope.getOrCreate(SingletonScope.java:80)
at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.findOrCreateSingletonBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2918)
at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2879)
at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2800)
at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1617)
at io.micronaut.context.AbstractBeanResolutionContext.getBean(AbstractBeanResolutionContext.java:66)
at io.micronaut.context.AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.resolveBean(AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.java:2065)
at io.micronaut.context.AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.getBeanForConstructorArgument(AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.java:1297)
at io.micronaut.configuration.hibernate.jpa.conf.$SessionFactoryPerDataSourceFactory$BuildHibernateSessionFactoryBuilder3$Definition.doBuild(Unknown Source)
at io.micronaut.context.AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.build(AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.java:769)
at io.micronaut.context.BeanDefinitionDelegate.build(BeanDefinitionDelegate.java:158)
at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveByBeanFactory(DefaultBeanContext.java:2354)
at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:2305)
at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:2251)
at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.createRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:3016)
at io.micronaut.context.SingletonScope.getOrCreate(SingletonScope.java:80)
at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.findOrCreateSingletonBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2918)
at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2879)
at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2800)
at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1617)
at io.micronaut.context.AbstractBeanResolutionContext.getBean(AbstractBeanResolutionContext.java:66)
at io.micronaut.context.AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.resolveBean(AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.java:2065)
at io.micronaut.context.AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.getBeanForConstructorArgument(AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.java:1297)
at io.micronaut.configuration.hibernate.jpa.conf.$SessionFactoryPerDataSourceFactory$BuildHibernateSessionFactoryBuilder4$Definition.build(Unknown Source)
at io.micronaut.context.BeanDefinitionDelegate.build(BeanDefinitionDelegate.java:161)
at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveByBeanFactory(DefaultBeanContext.java:2354)
at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:2305)
at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:2251)
at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.createRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:3016)
at io.micronaut.context.SingletonScope.getOrCreate(SingletonScope.java:80)
at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.findOrCreateSingletonBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2918)
at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2879)
at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2800)
at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.findBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1680)
at io.micronaut.context.BeanDefinitionDelegate.getParametersValues(BeanDefinitionDelegate.java:195)
at io.micronaut.context.BeanDefinitionDelegate.build(BeanDefinitionDelegate.java:157)
at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveByBeanFactory(DefaultBeanContext.java:2354)
at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:2305)
at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:2251)
at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.createRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:3016)
at io.micronaut.context.SingletonScope.getOrCreate(SingletonScope.java:80)
at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.findOrCreateSingletonBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2918)
at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.loadContextScopeBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:2737)
at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.initializeContext(DefaultBeanContext.java:1915)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at org.hibernate.boot.jaxb.internal.MappingBinder.doBind(MappingBinder.java:53)
at org.hibernate.boot.jaxb.internal.AbstractBinder.doBind(AbstractBinder.java:103)
at org.hibernate.boot.jaxb.internal.AbstractBinder.bind(AbstractBinder.java:58)
at org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.AdditionalJaxbMappingProducerImpl$1.addDocument(AdditionalJaxbMappingProducerImpl.java:103)
at org.hibernate.envers.configuration.internal.EntitiesConfigurator.configure(EntitiesConfigurator.java:111)
at org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.EnversServiceImpl.doInitialize(EnversServiceImpl.java:149)
at org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.EnversServiceImpl.initialize(EnversServiceImpl.java:113)
at org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.AdditionalJaxbMappingProducerImpl.produceAdditionalMappings(AdditionalJaxbMappingProducerImpl.java:110)
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:306)
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:86)
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:479)
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:85)
at org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources.buildMetadata(MetadataSources.java:202)
at io.micronaut.configuration.hibernate.jpa.conf.AbstractHibernateFactory.buildMetadata(AbstractHibernateFactory.java:92)
at io.micronaut.configuration.hibernate.jpa.conf.SessionFactoryPerDataSourceFactory.buildMetadata(SessionFactoryPerDataSourceFactory.java:88)
at io.micronaut.configuration.hibernate.jpa.conf.$SessionFactoryPerDataSourceFactory$BuildMetadata2$Definition.doBuild(Unknown Source)
at io.micronaut.context.AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.build(AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.java:769)
at io.micronaut.context.BeanDefinitionDelegate.build(BeanDefinitionDelegate.java:158)
at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveByBeanFactory(DefaultBeanContext.java:2354)
Caused by: org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.XsdException: Unable to locate schema [org/hibernate/jpa/orm_1_0.xsd] via classpath
at org.hibernate.boot.xsd.LocalXsdResolver.resolveLocalXsdSchema(LocalXsdResolver.java:90)
at org.hibernate.boot.xsd.LocalXsdResolver.buildXsdDescriptor(LocalXsdResolver.java:117)
at org.hibernate.boot.xsd.MappingXsdSupport.<init>(MappingXsdSupport.java:23)
at org.hibernate.boot.xsd.MappingXsdSupport.<clinit>(MappingXsdSupport.java:21)
Request loop failed with: Exception thrown instantiating MicronautLambdaRuntimeHandler
```

Here is a copy of the pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>envers</artifactId>
  <version>0.1</version>
  <packaging>${packaging}</packaging>

  <parent>
    <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
    <artifactId>micronaut-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.0</version>
  </parent>

  <properties>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <jdk.version>11</jdk.version>
    <release.version>11</release.version>
    <micronaut.version>3.8.0</micronaut.version>
    <micronaut.test.resources.enabled>true</micronaut.test.resources.enabled>
    <exec.mainClass>io.micronaut.function.aws.runtime.MicronautLambdaRuntime</exec.mainClass>
    <micronaut.data.version>3.9.1</micronaut.data.version>
    <micronaut.runtime>lambda</micronaut.runtime>
  </properties>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>central</id>
      <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-inject</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-validation</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut.aws</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-function-aws-api-proxy</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut.aws</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-function-aws-api-proxy-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut.aws</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-function-aws-custom-runtime</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-http-client</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-http-server-netty</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-jackson-databind</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut.data</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-data-hibernate-jpa</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut.sql</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-jdbc-hikari</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.annotation</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.annotation-api</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut.test</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-test-junit5</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-envers -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
      <version>5.6.11.Final</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jaxen</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxen</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>io.micronaut.build</groupId>
        <artifactId>micronaut-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
          </configuration>
      </plugin>
      
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <!-- Uncomment to enable incremental compilation -->
          <!-- <useIncrementalCompilation>false</useIncrementalCompilation> -->

          <annotationProcessorPaths combine.self="override">
            <path>
              <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
              <artifactId>micronaut-inject-java</artifactId>
              <version>${micronaut.version}</version>
            </path>
            <path>
              <groupId>io.micronaut.data</groupId>
              <artifactId>micronaut-data-processor</artifactId>
              <version>${micronaut.data.version}</version>
            </path>
            <path>
              <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
              <artifactId>micronaut-graal</artifactId>
              <version>${micronaut.version}</version>
            </path>
            <path>
              <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
              <artifactId>micronaut-http-validation</artifactId>
              <version>${micronaut.version}</version>
            </path>
            <path>
              <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
              <artifactId>micronaut-validation</artifactId>
              <version>${micronaut.version}</version>
            </path>
          </annotationProcessorPaths>
          <compilerArgs>
            <arg>-Amicronaut.processing.group=com.example</arg>
            <arg>-Amicronaut.processing.module=envers</arg>
          </compilerArgs>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

Here is a copy of my yaml:

```
micronaut:
  application:
    name: envers
datasources:
  default:
    url: ${database.url:`InsertDBUrl`}
    username: ${database.username:InsertUsername}
    password: ${database.password:InsertPassword}
    driverClassName: ${database.driver:com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver}
jpa:
  default:
    entity-scan:
      packages: 'com.example.model'
    properties:
      hibernate:
        hbm2ddl:
          auto: create
```

Here is a copy of my Entity:

```
package com.example.model;

import org.hibernate.envers.Audited;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Audited
public class EnversEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

A sample of this project can be found here also:

https://github.com/georgy3k/mn-envers

To create the native executable, I followed the following steps:

```
sdk install java 22.3.r11-grl
```

After installing GraalVM, install the native-image component, which is not installed by default:

```
gu install native-image
```

The command below generates a ZIP file which contains a GraalVM Native Executable of the application, and a bootstrap file which executes the native executable. The GraalVM Native Executable of the application is generated inside a Docker container.

```
./mvnw package -Dpackaging=docker-native -Dmicronaut.runtime=lambda -Pgraalvm
```